# Call function of just created object

Tags: php

How to call function of just created object without temporary variable?

Code

```
(new \Foo())->woof();
```

is not valid in php.

What is right?

Comment: There was some [discussion](http://markmail.org/message/i6muh556wanevtum) recently on this subject amongst the PHP core developers with, as-yet, no firm conclusions reached.

Comment: Why not define woof() as a static method?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It can work if the object has singleton

```
Foo::getInstance()->woof();
```

BTW: it doesn't have to be even singleton but also static method which returns the instance

```
class Foo {
      public static function & getInstance()
      {
         return new self();
      }
}
```

Comment: Gratuitous return by reference in the factory method.

Comment: That are good reasons for using a factory method, but doing so in order to avoid writing a few more characters when instantiating an object is not one of them.

Comment: -1 because: The return by reference is superfluous and even wrong. And only because of a detail you miss in the syntax of a language you should not change all your class definitions. That is not helpful and can not be the answer to a problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
$obj = new Foo();
$obj->woof();
```

If you have got PHP 5.4 or later, you can make use of a [new feature](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php):

> - Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. **`(new Foo)->bar()`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, but it's not very clean:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
  public function __construct()
  {
  }

  public function bar()
  {
    echo 'hello!';
  }
}

function Foo()
{
  return new Foo();
}

Foo()->bar();
```

You could also change it to something like

```
function newClass($className)
{
  return new $className();
}

newClass('Foo')->bar();
```

But the static method way is preferred.